# Add endpoints in Traffic Manager using python Azure SDK

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager, azure-sdk-python

I have a traffic manager profile in azure and I want to add endpoints to my traffic manager using my python script. I referred to the python sdk for azure to add the endpoints.

We can add or update endpoint using this function

```
tm_client.endpoints.create_or_update()
```

But I don't seem to understand the parameters which needs to be passed in this function. If anyone could post a sample code or help me out with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add an endpoint to Azure traffic manager, you need to define `Endpoint`
object, `profileName`, `groupName` and `endpointType`. Besides, **please note that we have to define different `Endpoint` object according to the endpoint type and traffic routing method**. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-trafficmanager/azure.mgmt.trafficmanager.models.endpoint(class)?view=azure-python).

For example. My traffic routing method is `Priority` and the endpoint type is `AzureEndpoints`

For example

1. Create a service principal and assign  `Contributor` role to the sp

```
az login
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role contributor \
    --scopes /subscriptions/{SubID} --sdk-auth true
```

2. Code

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.trafficmanager import TrafficManagerManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.trafficmanager.models import EndpointStatus, Endpoint

client_id = "<sp appId>"
secret = "<sp password>"
tenant = "<sp tenant>"
subscription_ID = "<>"

tm_client = TrafficManagerManagementClient(creds, subscription_ID)
# define endpoint
param = Endpoint(
    # my target resource is app service
    target_resource_id='/subscriptions/<>/resourceGroups/<>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<>',
    endpoint_status=EndpointStatus.enabled,
    priority=1
)
result = tm_client.endpoints.create_or_update(
    resource_group_name='testsignlar',
    profile_name='test05',
    endpoint_type='AzureEndpoints',
    endpoint_name='mypoint',
    parameters=param)

print(result.id)
```

[image]
[image]